Why aren't a starship's weapons always powered?
During scenarios such as the Dominion War, it would make sense to be constantly ready for anything by having the weapons always ready.
I can perhaps accept that having one's weapons powered can be detected and considered threatening, but that wouldn't seem much of a problem in wartime.
Is there a canonical reason, technical, procedural or otherwise, that is preventing a starship from having its offensive systems constantly powered?


Long-range sensors get blurry. 2) Wasting power that could be used to make coffee or Earl Grey. 3) Then the bridge officer's dramatic line to turn the shields on would be gone making any encounter less dramatic.


They use a lot of power and starships do not have unlimited power.  Not to mention the wear/tear/usage on them that may not be much but using all the time would add up.  Plus you can not beam through shields, so anytime you wanted to beam something and shields were up have to take down/etc.

If you go everywhere with your weapons armed, you have nowhere to escalate except actual firing. If your weapons are powered down, then activating them becomes a powerful signal of "whatever you're doing, stop it right now or else".

@Cadence Doesn't that apply more to offensive weapons, not to purely defensive capabilities such as shields?

@gidds Even if shields are "purely defensive" they're still used primarily in combat. Shields signal that you think a fight is imminent - and if your opponent knows they don't mean to start a fight, they'll have to wonder if you mean to start a fight.

@Cadence Isn't that circular logic?  Shields only signal an imminent fight if they're not usually raised until an imminent fight.  But if Federation starships customarily ran with shields up, then they wouldn't signal anything.

And one more. Manpower. US Navy Ships have 3x the crew needed to run it. That way you have 3 rotating watch sections of people running the ship underway. (3 section each doing 8 hours a day, typically two 4 hours watches a day) BUT when manning Battle Stations to fight, (AKA Star Trek's "Shields Up, Power Weapons") EVERYONE is up and manning stations. Because weapons & defensive stations are not normally manned. (IIRC it took 40-50 people to man each 16" turrets on the Iowa class Battleships) And you have many Damage Control parties standing by to do repairs.

The phasers are extremely power-hungry systems. Constantly running them places them under significant strain, as well as limiting other useful systems (like the warp engines) from running at their full capacity.
Per the Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual, once the phasers are made ready, there is a finite amount of time that they can be held in this state; 45 minutes if the ship is in 'Cruise Mode' (e.g. with the stardrive section attached) and less than 15 minutes if it's the saucer module on its own.

In Cruise Mode, all phaser arrays receive their primary power from the
warp reaction chamber, with supplementary fusion power from the
impulse engine systems. Recharge times are kept to <0.5 seconds. Full
power firing endurance is rated at =45 minutes.
In Separated Flight Mode, the Saucer Module is cut off from the main
electro plasma system, and it must then rely on increased fusion
generator output to power the arrays. Recharge times can be maintained
at <0.5 seconds, but firing endurance drops to <15 minutes.


Wait...so the phasers take more power than the warp drive itself?

@MichaelStachowsky - No, but they take use a significant amount of power that's
now no longer available to the warp drive.

In non-combat having your weapons active is viewed as a sign of aggression in unexplored space.
During the dominion war, ships WOULD have weapons systems active in combat zone.
In Yellow Alert situations its optional to have shields raised and weapons on standby.
But it makes no sense keep power intensive weapons active 24/7.
Shields may typically be up. Not weapons. In situation where they're in Direct combat weapons would be Active such as immediate patrol or escort duties. But Distances of typical weapons is measured shortly. Phasers have a typical range 300,000 kilometers and Projectile weapons like torpedoes 3 Million km. Vast distances of space, you wait til you have sufficient close to fire.

Except that they don't have them active, even at the height of the war.
